# Python Add_Lowest to sns.lineplt

Tags: python, matplotlib, statsmodels

How can i make the line disappear?

```
rmodel = sm.GLM.from_formula("rBPXSY1 ~ rRIDAGEYR", data=da)
res = rmodel.fit()
res.summary()

pp = sns.lineplot(da.rRIDAGEYR,da.rBPXSY1,alpha=0.4, marker='o', ls='')
add_lowess(pp)
```

**Intended result**

[image]

**My result **

[image]

Comment: statsmodels' `add_lowess` needs the plot to be a lineplot. `ax = sns.lineplot(y=..., x=..., alpha=0.4, marker='o', ls='')` or maybe `ax = sns.lineplot(y=..., x=..., alpha=0.4, marker='o', ls='')`. And then `add_lowess(ax)`. Don't forget to add `from statsmodels.graphics.regressionplots import add_lowess` to your code.

Comment: Hi JohanC thanks, i will try that out. However the tutorial answer given was that the data was plotted in scatterplot (shown above in intended result). Do you mean that i plot both scatterplot and lineplot and then use the lineplot for the `add_lowess(ax)` then hide the lineplot?

Comment: With `ax = sns.lineplot(y=..., x=..., alpha=0.4, marker='o', ls='')` you create a lineplot that looks like a scatterplot.

Comment: Hi i have modified accordingly, the red line is showing however the line traces is still be seen. Anyway totally eliminate it?

Comment: Are you using the latest versions of seaborn and matplotlib?   Maybe setting `ls='none'` works in your case.  By the way, it is recommended to call the return value of `sns.lineplot` something like `ax` to ease understanding how matplotlib retouches to the subplot can be called.

Answer (score 1):

When using the latest versions of each package, and running

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from statsmodels.graphics.regressionplots import add_lowess

g = np.random.default_rng(0)
x = g.random(size=1000)
y = 5*np.sin(2*np.pi*x) + g.standard_normal(1000)
pp = sns.lineplot(x=x,y=y,alpha=0.4, marker='o', ls='')
pp = add_lowess(pp)
```

you get an image like the one you desire:

[image: Scatter with LOWESS]